# Customer Passenger Error Pages

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

How do you replace the Passenger Application failed to load error messages. They are lovely, but I'd rather not display them when we move our application to production. It'd be better to just show them on the dev box and maintenance page on the live site.

For clarification, this is the call stack page passenger displays when your rails app fails to load.

I'd rather not modify the passenger template files directly.

Passenger doesn't seem to be respecting:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the Passenger directive:

```
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages off
```

additionally to the ErrorDocument directives for Apache that you want, in order to disable the Passenger error page.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Phusion Passenger, set the following within your Apache virtual host:

`PassengerErrorOverride on`

`ErrorDocument 500 /path/to/500.html`

Answer (score 1):

If it's the 500 error you're getting / wanting to show something different, you should be able to just change the 500.html page in your rails app under the public folder. Sorry if you already, but that sounds like what you're trying to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/templates
```

(Your lib/gem path may vary.)